# How to keep alive socket.io when app enters background mode in swift?

Tags: swift, socket.io, background

I have a location tracker app for IOS which should send current location even if app is in background mode. But socket.io dies when app enters background mode. Is there a way to keep it alive?

Comment: You should share the code. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You should't use Socket IO for background tasks.

Use notifications to achieve the desired behaviour: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

You can also use Background App Refresh: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh

Comment: No, you don't need to show the notification. You can use it as a tool to receive information and perform some background task. When the user open the app, then you enable socket, but for background communication tool, notifications is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Friend use this simple code to keep alive your app in background--

```
var backgroundUpdateTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier(rawValue: 0)

func endBackgroundUpdateTask() {
    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundUpdateTask)
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier.invalid
}
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.backgroundUpdateTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: {
        self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()
    })
}
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    self.endBackgroundUpdateTask()

}
```

i hope this code will work fine

Comment: It will work but for about 30 seconds and then iOS will put your app into a background state anyway. Background task is only supposed to be used to do a small amount of house keeping before entering background